# GKTurnBasedMatch - Obtaining the End Date

Tags: ios, iphone, game-center, gamekit

I am currently building an iPhone turn-based game that utilizes Game Center for all network functionality. I created a custom UI to display matches in a UITableView where the local player can enter, create, quit, and delete a game.

My issue is that in my cells, I want to display relevant dates (last turn taken, match created when no turn is taken yet, and match ended date for ended match status). For the life of me, I can't seem to figure out a good way to derive the exact date and time a match ended. The GKTurnBasedMatch object has the creationDate property which is great, but there is no property for when the match ended.

Currently I am just pulling the last turn date of one of the participants, but obviously that is not even close to optimal. I'm thinking the best workaround is to encode the current date in the matchData object sent when endMatchInTurn is called, but I'm hoping I'm missing a better solution somewhere in the API.

Thanks!
Corbin

Answer (score 0):

After much research, there is no valid way to actually obtain the time when a GKTurnBasedMatch ended via the -endMatchInTurnWithMatchData method within the GameKit API. However, I do have a perfectly viable solution which just required a little bit of extra work. For whatever object you use to encode your matchData property, just assign another property and make it an NSDate. Then right before calling the endMatch method, set the new NSDate property to [NSDate date], which returns the current date and time, and archive it before sending as the matchData object. My own code is below:

```
GameState *stateToSave = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:matchToQuit.matchData];
stateToSave.matchEndDate = [NSDate date];
NSData *endGameData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:stateToSave];
[matchToQuit endMatchInTurnWithMatchData:endGameData completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    // Code
}
```